# Algolia autocomplete - function footerTemplate causes SCRIPT1010: Expected Identifier error

Tags: javascript, jquery, algolia

I'm using Algolia autocomplete (JQuery).

It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox etc, but Internet Explorer 11

On IE, it causes the SCRIPT1010: Expected Identifier error, from the line with function footerTemplate

I have no idea what to do about this; any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

Here's some excerpts from my code:

```
var client = algoliasearch('{{ getenv('ALGOLIA_APP_ID') }}', '{{ getenv('ALGOLIA_PUBLIC') }}');
                var index_classes = client.initIndex('classes');
                var index_stories = client.initIndex('articles');

jQuery(function($) {
                var client = algoliasearch('{{ getenv('ALGOLIA_APP_ID') }}', '{{ getenv('ALGOLIA_PUBLIC') }}');
                var index_classes = client.initIndex('classes');
                var index_stories = client.initIndex('articles');

                if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                    nr_res = 3;
                    nr_res_2 = 1;
                } else {
                    nr_res = 5;
                    nr_res_2 = 5;
                }

                $('input[name="search_text"]').autocomplete(
                    { debug:true,
                        templates: {
                            footer: '<div id="see-all-sr"><hr><a href="#" style="size:16px;padding-left:12px;color:blue;text-decoration:underline">See all results in detail</a><br>&nbsp</div>'
                        }
                    }, [
                        {
                            source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(index_classes, { hitsPerPage: nr_res }),
                            displayKey: 'name',
                            name: 'class',
                            templates: {
                                header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Classes (top ' + nr_res + ')</div>',
                                suggestion: function(suggestion) {
                                    return '<img src="/images/class/' + suggestion.id + '_100.jpg">' + '<div><span>' +
                                        suggestion._highlightResult.name.value + '</span><span>'
                                        + suggestion._highlightResult.teacher_name.value + '</span>';
                                },
                                empty: '<div class="aa-empty">No results. See <a style="color:blue;text-decoration:underline" href="/classes">all classes</a></div>',
                                footer: function footerTemplate({ query, isEmpty }) {
                                    if (!isEmpty) {
                                        $('#see-all-sr').show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(index_stories, { hitsPerPage: nr_res_2 }),
                            displayKey: 'title',
                            name: 'story',
                            templates: {
                                header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Stories (top ' + nr_res_2 + ')</div>',
                                suggestion: function(suggestion) {
                                    return '<img src="/images/article/' + suggestion.id + '_100.jpg">' + '<div><span>' +
                                        suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + '</span><span>' +
                                        suggestion._highlightResult.author_name.value + '</span></div>';
                                },
                                empty: '<div class="aa-empty">No results. See <a style="color:blue;text-decoration:underline" href="/stories">all stories</a></div>',
                                footer: function footerTemplate({ query, isEmpty }) {
                                    if (!isEmpty) {
                                        $('#see-all-sr').show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    ]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) { // https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#jquery
                    window.location = '/' + suggestion.url;
                }).on('autocomplete:empty', function() {
                    $('#see-all-sr').hide();
                });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The function definition is using ES6 syntax which IE11 doesn't support.

Replace the function definition with this:

```
footer: function footerTemplate(obj) {
  if (!obj.isEmpty) {
    $('#see-all-sr').show();
  }
}
```